# Changing development team in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm a member of two Apple development programs and I'm trying to upload a new app. The problem is that every time I log in to itunesconnect it logs me in to one team and I can't find a way to switch teams.  I've tried logging in on developer.apple.com first and choosing the correct team but as soon as I go to itunesconnect it re-logs me in to the wrong team.

Is there any way to change teams on itunesconnect?  I've tried this in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox and I've cleared my history and cache.

Thanks

Comment: I'm tearing my head out!   Did you solve this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Update:** Here it is, my precious:

[image]
Just invite your usual Apple ID in each desired team's Users and Roles section, click a link from the invitation email and you're done!

---

<strike>It really seems that you can't use the same iTunes Connect account for multiple teams.</strike>

But what I've recently found out is that you can have **multiple iTC accounts under the same email** by using plus-tagged emails for registration. Thus, my iTunes Connect account IDs look like
**myusername+someteam@gmail.com** and **myusername+anotherteam@gmail.com**, which means two different email addresses for Apple but actually a single email account for me.

Would be happy to hear about any possible downsides of such an approach, though I really find it more convenient than dealing with a bunch of emails and Apple IDs for different dev teams.

Comment: This sounds like an ideal solution. Thanks!

Comment: You saved me from a mess :-)

Comment: OK so I'm trying this approach, but how do I switch to the different account?  It seemed like the first time I got prompted to choose, but then every time I log in afterwards it's that same account.

Comment: You can ‘switch’ only by logging out: http://take.ms/z491W :-)
Or use private browsing windows, which I actually prefer.

Comment: Interesting; I can do that on the certs/identifiers page (it takes me here https://developer.apple.com/account/selectTeam.action), but do not have that option on iTunes Connect proper (to manage the apps). EDIT I now notice @gonzobrains comment in the other answer and wonder if I'm hosed...

Comment: The downside is that it becomes really hard to be an internal tester, using the Testflight iOS app, because that's tied directly to the Apple ID you use on iOS. Apple is not making this very easy.

Comment: Well, they don't have to register in iTC with their _actual_ Apple IDs to test an app; that is explicitly mentioned in TestFlight's invitation emails. I actually send my internal tester invitations to plus-tagged emails as well — they "register" those new Apple IDs and forget them forever.

Comment: hey @GlebA. can you please upload some snapshot, i am trying this way but not working, may be i am doing something wrong...

Comment: @bLacKhoLE Where exactly are you stuck and what kind of error or whatever are you getting?

Comment: i developer center i can able to select team. but when i got login with iTunesConnect i cant able to show option for select team or switch team. i read your post but not able to understand what exactly i have to do ??? @GlebA.

Comment: To let you access the iTunes Connect page of a team, its Team Agent or Admin must send you an invitation (https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Users%20and%20Roles_Adding%20and%20Removing%20Users). You will then be asked to create a new Apple ID. Given the registration form, use your usual email but with a +someteam tag as described above.

Comment: See answer of @Mariano Paniga!

Comment: Yes, it is now possible to do this. @Mariano Paniga answer is correct.

Answer (score 14):

Now it is possible to select the team also into iTunesConnect site. But you need to invite the team member by using it's email in both MemberCenter site and iTunesConnect site.

Comment: I had invited someone in iTunesConnect, but they weren't working in Member Center until I saw this post and invited them there to. This answer works as of Sept 2016

Comment: been stuck on this for ages ! Thank you !

Answer (score 13):

I've talked to Apple and their answer is to create a new Apple ID for each development team and then use that Apple ID to log in to iTunesConnect.  It seems like there should be a better way but after several emails and a phone conversation, this is what they recommend doing.

Comment: the member center allows you to choose different teams for the same ID but itunes connect doesn't?  ridiculous.

Comment: A long time ago, didn't Apple's developer agreement prohibit devs from having multiple accounts?  (Not that people didn't do it, but I thought it was "illegal."  I might be mis-remembering, but I'd-a swore I remember reading that and it being a big deal where I used to work.  (This is several years ago, though, so things may have changed.)

Comment: See answer of @Mariano Paniga!