# How do I prepare a new version to be uploaded for a different organization?

Tags: app-store-connect

When I'm on https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/ and click my apps it only shows the ones under the organization that belongs to my user. So I'm uncertain how to get into the view for a different organization so I can prepare a new version to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Once you log in on iTunes Connect you can select the organization you want to use. You will see this message if your Apple ID is associated with multiple developer teams.

Update: This only works for [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/). Check [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529000/changing-development-team-in-itunes-connect) for a possible solution.

Comment: It doesn't do that on the itunes connect URL that I provided, it only does that for http://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action

Comment: It seems you are right. I have found another user that has asked the same question. It seems that it is not possible to use iTunes Connect with multiple accounts. I suggest logging in to the original iTunes Connect account directly.